# Best Linear Prediction and variance decomposition

Tags: statistics, expectation

Let $( X , Y )$ have moments of at least the second order ,and let $\hat{Y} = a +bX$ then  we will choose the coefficients $a$ and $b$ such that $a=E(Y)-\sigma_{XY}/\sigma_{X}^2E(X)$ and $b=\sigma_{XY}/\sigma_{X}^2$ , so that $\hat{Y}$ is the best linear prediction of $Y$ , where best is taken to mean “minimum expected squared distance between outcomes of $Y$ and outcomes of $\hat{Y}$".

Now define $V= Y - \hat{Y}$ to represent the deviations between outcomes of $Y$ and outcomes of the best linear prediction of $Y$ .

How can I prove that $\mathbb E((Y-\mathbb E(Y))^2) =\sigma_{Y}^2\rho_{XY}^2 + \sigma_{Y}^2 (1-\rho _{XY}^2).$ ?

My attempt is :

If $\hat{Y}$ is the best prediction of $Y$ then $E(Y)=E(\hat{Y})$ that means $E(V)=0$
Then $E((Y-E(Y))^2)=E((\hat{Y}-E(\hat{Y})+V)^2)= \sigma_{\hat{Y}}^2 + \sigma_{V}^2 +\sigma_{\hat{Y}V}$ .

And $\sigma_{V}^2 =E(Y-\hat{Y})^2 =E((Y-(a+bX))^2)=E((Y-(E(Y)-\sigma_{XY}/\sigma_{X}^2E(X)+\sigma_{XY}/\sigma_{X}^2 X))^2) $

I could not do anything more

How can I prove that :
$$\sigma_{\hat{Y}}^2 + \sigma_{V}^2 +\sigma_{\hat{Y}V}=\sigma_{Y}^2\rho_{XY}^2 + \sigma_{Y}^2 (1-\rho _{XY}^2)$$

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please include in post your thoughts and attempts.

Comment: @probablyme I edited the question , but it is not a great attempt

Comment: All I have are pointers. If I am not mistaken, 1. have you tried $\sigma_{\hat Y}^2 = \text{Var}(a+bX)$? 2. $\sigma_V^2 = \text{Var}(Y-\hat Y)$? 3. $\sigma_{\hat YV} = \text{Cov}(a+bX,Y-\hat Y)$? Include, in post.

Comment: @probablyme $a=E(Y)-\sigma_{XY}/\sigma_{X}^2E(X)$
 and $b=\sigma_{XY}/\sigma_{X}^2$ I added that to the post .